# How do I make a simple makefile for gcc on Linux?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have three files: `program.c`, `program.h` and `headers.h`.

`program.c` includes `program.h` and `headers.h`.

I need to compile this on Linux using *gcc* compiler.  I'm not sure how to do this. Netbeans created one for me, but it's empty.

Comment: There is an extremely elegant (and well documented) solution at https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/08/26/makefile-c-projects/.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Interesting, I didn't know make would default to using the C compiler given rules regarding source files.

Anyway, a simple solution that demonstrates simple Makefile concepts would be:

```
HEADERS = program.h headers.h

default: program

program.o: program.c $(HEADERS)
    gcc -c program.c -o program.o

program: program.o
    gcc program.o -o program

clean:
    -rm -f program.o
    -rm -f program
```

*(bear in mind that make requires tab instead of space indentation, so be sure to fix that when copying)*

However, to support more C files, you'd have to make new rules for each of them.  Thus, to improve:

```
HEADERS = program.h headers.h
OBJECTS = program.o

default: program

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    gcc -c $< -o $@

program: $(OBJECTS)
    gcc $(OBJECTS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f $(OBJECTS)
    -rm -f program
```

I tried to make this as simple as possible by omitting variables like $(CC) and $(CFLAGS) that are usually seen in makefiles.  If you're interested in figuring that out, I hope I've given you a good start on that.

Here's the Makefile I like to use for C source.  Feel free to use it:

```
TARGET = prog
LIBS = -lm
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

It uses the wildcard and patsubst features of the make utility to automatically include .c and .h files in the current directory, meaning when you add new code files to your directory, you won't have to update the Makefile.  However, if you want to change the name of the generated executable, libraries, or compiler flags, you can just modify the variables.

In either case, don't use autoconf, please.  I'm begging you!  :)

Comment: To be technically correct, I believe you should use `.PHONY: clean all default` for those targets that are meant to be used from the command line. Also, Autoconf/Automake aren't that bad. Sure, they feel awful, and getting used to them is about as fun as forcing your head through a brick wall, but they do work, and they're well developed, and they'll cover most of your bases as far as portability, and will make your life a lot easier in the end once you get used to their awful design.

Comment: I guess this works, but I thought if I typed "make" on the terminal the program should run. This is what I get:
gcc  statsh.o -Wall -lm -o prog

Is it possible to just type make and execute the program?

Comment: where would you add the openmp flag -fopenmp

Comment: You sure this works? Even after copying and pasting your first example directly this gives "Cannot find the file specified", listing the .o file. Pretty sure it isn't creating the .o first

Comment: @krb686: Thanks for letting me know.  Did you make sure the makefile is indented with tabs instead of spaces?

Comment: Why don't use autoconf joey-adams ?

Comment: If anyone wonders why there are dashes in front of `rm`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989465/rm-rf-versus-rm-rf

Comment: @JoeyAdams I use `make -n -f Makefile hello.c` but results `make: Nothing to be done for `hello.c'.` my [Makefile](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25895072/)   ` #This is assignment 1, week one of System Programming of Griffith University.
 #@author: alhelal
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
hello : hello.o
 $(CC) -o $@ $<
hello.o : hello.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<`

Comment: Isn't the `$(HEADERS)` in `%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)` unnecessary? You get all of the existing header files with `HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)`, and then assert that they must all exist.

Comment: Better use `:=` instead of `=`. With `:=` the `wildcard` function just runs once and one can append/extend variables later `OBJS := $(OBJS) other.o`. With `=` this is not possible, it will cause an infinite loop in the variable expansion! See: [The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors).

Answer (score 27):

For example this simple Makefile should be sufficient:

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall

all: program
program: program.o
program.o: program.c program.h headers.h

clean:
    rm -f program program.o
run: program
    ./program
```

Note there must be `<tab>` on the next line after clean and run, not spaces.

*UPDATE* Comments below applied

Comment: @user69514: `make` with no arguments usually only *build* your software. To run it, either use `make run` (available in this answer, but not necessarily in all `Makefile`s), or run it directly: `./program`

Answer (score 15):

```
all: program
program.o: program.h headers.h
```

is enough. the rest is implicit

Comment: And if your whole program is a single `.c` file, only `program:` is necessary. Sweet :)

Comment: While this is surely simple, no doubt, anonymous & @MestreLion , I am new to C, and have only recently split a large project into 2 source files and a header, and I am **not** using makefiles but rather a *very* simple C program that basically just uses `system()` from `stdlib.h`... No cons of this approach, are there ?

Comment: @APJo: with simple projects you can get away without a `Makefile` and simply directly invoke `gcc *.c *.h -o program`, possibly adding options like `-Wall -O2`, etc.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest make file can be

```
all : test

test : test.o
        gcc -o test test.o 

test.o : test.c
        gcc -c test.c

clean :
        rm test *.o
```

Comment: you can add more detail to explain what your Makefile does

Comment: you can actually go a lot simpler. see @anonymous 1 liner

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of headers and your development habits, you may want to investigate gccmakedep. This program examines your current directory and adds to the end of the makefile the header dependencies for each .c/cpp file. This is overkill when you have 2 headers and one program file. However, if you have 5+ little test programs and you are editing one of 10 headers, you can then trust make to rebuild exactly those programs which were changed by your modifications.