# rm -rf versus -rm -rf

Tags: makefile

In a Makefile, I read:

-rm -rf (instead of rm -rf). What does the first "-" mean at the beginning of the line in a Makefile ?

Comment: Make is a programming language, not just an utility.  Makefiles are programs!  Don't say that this belongs to superuser!

Comment: FYI, `\rm` can also be used instead of `-rm`.

Comment: Note also that Make predefines `$(RM)` which you might want to use, for maximum portability.

Answer (score 58):

It means that `make` itself will ignore any error code from `rm`.

In a `makefile`, if any command fails then the `make` process itself discontinues processing. By prefixing your commands with `-`, you notify `make` that it should continue processing rules no matter the outcome of the command.

For example, the makefile rule:

```
clean:
    rm *.o
    rm *.a
```

will *not* remove the `*.a` files if `rm *.o` returns an error (if, for example, there aren't any `*.o` files to delete). Using:

```
clean:
    -rm *.o
    -rm *.a
```

will fix that particular problem.

---

*Aside:* Although it's probably not needed in your specific case (since the `-f` flag appears to prevent `rm` from returning an error when the file does not exist), it's still good practice to mark the line explicitly in the `makefile` - `rm` may return *other* errors under certain circumstances and it makes your intent clear.

Comment: @user255607 (if that is your real name). Mark it as answered then (green tick next to the answer)