# Multiple files Makefile compilation

Tags: c++, makefile

How do compile 2 .cpp files and 1 .h file in a makefile?
I am noob with makefile but I don't want to do it in the command line all the time (Because I need to add libraries and linker options etc. but I know how to do that).

I've done a ton of research, including the manual, but I still don't get it.

Here's the makefile I wrote:

```
HEADERS = program.h headers.h

default: program

program.o: program.cpp $(HEADERS)
    g++ -c program.cpp -o program.o

program: program.o
    g++ program.o -o program

clean:
    -rm -f program.o
    -rm -f program
```

The makefile I have is for 1 file. How do I do it for 3 files (2 .cpp, 1 .h)?

**ANY** help is much appreciated.

Comment: Start with the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Comment: @remyabel don't worry :) I'm not that dumb

Comment: The manual is actually a pretty good resource. Tutorials can be kind of all over the place.

Comment: Post the makefile you've tried to write.  Describe what doesn't work or what parts you can't figure out.  We'll answer specific questions about specific problems, but we won't just write your code for you.  That's not what SO is about.

Comment: Well, cat, all we know about you is this very very basic question. There are only two possibilities, and remyabel was so kind to choose the more flattering one (but everything is relative): That you actually didn't bother to *read*  the manual. Because if you had: Why would you ask this really really basic question? The only conceivable answer to that would be the even less flattering assumption.

Comment: If you only have 2 files, and not planning to add more, you can use a script: `g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp` (assuming your compiler is `g++`)

Comment: @CATspellsDOG Pro tip: `make` provides you with implicit rules to compile `.c` to `.o`.

Comment: @anatolyg how would I add a `.h` file?

Comment: @CATspellsDOG You don't need to "compile" h-files. Maybe this was the bit that made it all so difficult for you. You only need to compile the `cpp` files. Header files are included in the `makefile` just for `make` to figure out when to recompile the source files.

Comment: BTW example seems to be taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1484873/509868)

Comment: @anatolyg nope. I watched a tutorial on it and that was the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a simple makefile? GCC Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484817/how-do-i-make-a-simple-makefile-gcc-unix/1484873)

Comment: Fascinating that your makefile is *exactly* the one from the question @remyabel posted - **including that it compiles C files, not CPP files**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for `anatolyg` for explaining:

> **You don't need to "compile" h-files** Maybe this was the bit that made it all so difficult for you. You only need to compile the cpp files. Header files are included in the makefile just for make to figure out when to recompile the source files.

Thanks to that, I figured out I just need to make a makefile to compile 2 .cpp files and it handles the rest.

Greatly Appreciated `anatolyg`. Thank you :)