# Why does directly compiling by gcc in the terminal work but not with a make file?

Tags: c, user-interface, gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile a GTK+ example using make, but when I run it, the terminal says "make: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop."

However, when I compile by typing the following, it compiles successfully.

```
gcc -g -Wall -o exampleapp main.c exampleapp.c exampleapp.h exampleappwin.c exampleappwin.h -export-dynamic `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Here's what I put in my make file:

```
NAME=exampleapp
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -o $(NAME)
GTKFLAGS=-export-dynamic `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
SRCS=                           \
    main.c                      \
    exampleapp.c exampleapp.h   \
    exampleappwin.c exampleappwin.h 
CC=gcc

all: main

main: $(SRCS)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) $(GTKFLAGS)

clean:
/bin/rm -f $(NAME)
```

Is something wrong with my make file? If so, how can I correct it?

Comment: I get `Makefile:13: *** missing separator.  Stop.`. When I fix the tabs, it seems to work. I would suggest you review [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1484873/2970947).

Comment: The line starting `$(CC)` should be tabbed in

Comment: Okay, thanks. But now I get "gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory". I wonder how it can find the gtk header file successfully when not using the make file though. Aren't the two I mentioned the same?

Comment: Please add the **output from make in each step**.

Comment: the targets (all and clean) do not actually produce a file of that name, so there should be, before any of those targets, the line: `.PHONY: all clean`

Comment: do NOT place header files amongst the list of `SRC` files

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some tabs in the rule section of your Makefile.

It should look like:

```
all: main

main: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) $(GTKFLAGS)

clean:
    /bin/rm -f $(NAME)
```

Note that the action lines must be indented with a **literal tab character**, not with spaces. (Stack Overflow converts the tab to four spaces -- don't just copy and paste!)

Answer (score 0):

there are a few problems with the posted makefile.

Suggest using the following, which has recipe lines properly indented with a `<tab>`  and generates macros using `:=` so they are not re-evaluated every time they are referenced in the makefile.

This sample makefile also corrects the recipes for compiling and linking

```
NAME=exampleapp

CFLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c

GTKFLAGS := -export-dynamic `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

SRCS :=            \
    main.c         \
    exampleapp.c   \
    exampleappwin.c 

OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

HDRS := exampleapp.h examplappwin.h

CC := /usr/bin/gcc
RM := /bin/rm

.PSEUDO: all clean

all: $(NAME)

%.o:%.c $(HDRS)
<tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< -I.

$(NAME): $(OBS)
<tab>$(CC)  $> $(GTKFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
<tab>$(RM) -f $(NAME) $(OBJS)
```

Note: the `<tab>` must be replaced in the actual file with a tab character