# How do I recursively find source files in subdirectories in Makefile?

Tags: recursion, makefile

I'm quite new to [makefile](/questions/tagged/makefile) but I still cannot understand how to set up the subdirectories of my source files.

My directory tree is:

```
i18n/
src/
    engine/
    graphics/ (currently only directory used)
```

I'm using [this premade `Makefile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484817/how-do-i-make-a-simple-makefile-for-gcc-on-linux/1484873#1484873):

```
TARGET = caventure
LIBS = -lSDL2
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall
TGTDIR = build

.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -Wall $(LIBS) -o $(TGTDIR)/$(TARGET)

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU make's `wildcard` function does not recursively visit all subdirectories.
You need a recursive variant of it, which can be implemented as described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18258352/1221106

So, instead of `$(wildcard *.cpp)` you need to use that recursive wildcard function.

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler way of finding files recursively might be to just use `find`.

For example, if you have a layout like this.

```
$ tree .
.
├── d1
│   └── foo.txt
├── d2
│   ├── d4
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   └── foo.txt
├── d3
│   └── foo.txt
└── Makefile
```

You could write a Makefile like this.

```
index.txt: $(shell find . -name "*.txt")                                             
    echo $^
```

Which prints this.

```
$ make
echo d2/d4/foo.txt d2/foo.txt d1/foo.txt d3/foo.txt
d2/d4/foo.txt d2/foo.txt d1/foo.txt d3/foo.txt
```