# Shortcut when writing a custom compile command in c++.

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, hyperlink, compilation

I am trying to run a custom c++ file so that it can link to Matlab and do the plotting.  So far, my command in terminal to compile the .cpp file is as follow:

```
g++ inputfile.cpp -o outoutfile -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/extern/include -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64 -leng -lmx -lm -lmat -lut -lstdc++
```

The outputfile is then ran as:

```
./outputfile
```

Question is: Is there a shortcut so that I dont have to type out the path to include and links every time?

Please help, thanks.

P/S.  I am currently on a Ubuntu machine, and I really do not want to go the IDE route (Visual Studio, CodeBlocks,.. etc.).  I just want to code in a simple text editor, with terminal open to compile and run.

So far, I have tried 2 approaches: the 1st one is to have a text editor, a terminal and I manually enter the compile (with linked library syntax). This works every time but I got tired of writing the syntax all the time.

The 2nd approach is to use Sublime Text, I have made a custom built.  This works half of the time.

Comment: Makefile, or more advanced build system.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach is to prepare Makefile and setup required goals there. Then you would just run something like:

```
make outputfile
./outputfile
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484873/7934249) has a very good introduction into the simple makefile.