# Understanding makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I was looking at [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/) flow diagram to understand how makefiles really operate but I'm still struggling to 100% understand what's going on.

I have a main.cpp file that calls upon some function that is defined in function.h and function.cpp. Then, I'm given the makefile:

```
main: main.cpp function.o
    g++ main.cpp function.o -o main

mainAssembly: main.cpp
    g++ -S main.cpp

function.o: function.cpp
    g++ -c function.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.S main

linkerError: main.cpp function.o
    g++ main.cpp function.o -o main
```

What's going on? From what I understand so far is that we are compiling function.cpp, which turns into an object file? Why is this necessary?

I don't know what the `mainAssembly` part is really doing. I tried reading the g++ flags but I still have trouble understand what this is. Is this just compiling main.cpp with the headers? Shouldn't we also convert main into an object file as well?

I guess `main` is simply linking everything together into an exe called main? And I'm completely lost on what `clean` and `linkerError` are trying to do. Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

That flowchart confuses more than it explains as it seems needlessly complicated. Each step is actually quite simple in isolation, and there's no point in jamming them all into one chart.

Remember a `Makefile` simply establishes a dependency chain, an order of operations which it tries to follow, where the file on the left is dependent on the files on the right.

Here's your first part where `function.o` is the *product of* `function.cpp`:

```
function.o: function.cpp
    g++ -c function.cpp
```

If `function.cpp` changes, then the `.o` file must be rebuilt. This is perhaps incomplete if `function.h` exists, as `function.cpp` might `#include` it, so the correct definition is probably:

```
function.o: function.cpp function.h
    g++ -c function.cpp
```

Now if you're wondering why you'd build a single `.cpp` into a single `.o` file, consider programs at a much larger scale. You don't want to recompile every source file every time you change anything, you only want to compile the things that are directly impacted by your changes. Editing `function.cpp` should only impact `function.o`, and not `main.o` as that's unrelated. However, changing `function.h` might impact `main.o` because of a reference in `main.cpp`. It depends on how things are referenced with `#include`.

This part is a little odd:

```
mainAssembly: main.cpp
    g++ -S main.cpp
```

That just dumps out the compiled assembly code for `main.cpp`. This is an optional step and isn't necessary for building the final executable.

This part ham-fistedly assembles the two parts:

```
main: main.cpp function.o
    g++ main.cpp function.o -o main
```

I say that because *normally* you'd compile all `.cpp` files to `.o` and then link the `.o` files together with your `libstdc++` library and any other shared libraries you're using with a tool like `ld`, the linker. The final step in any typical compilation is linking to produce a binary executable or library, though `g++` will silently do this for you when directed to, like here.

I think there's much better examples to work from than what you have here. This file is just full of confusion.

Comment: Thank you! Can you re-explain what you meant when you redefined function.o? Are you saying we may need to include function.h in case function.cpp includes it in its code? Also, how would a better compilation exactly look like?

Comment: [This answer on Makefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484817/how-do-i-make-a-simple-makefile-for-gcc-on-linux) looks a lot more conventional. Every `.h` file that you've made, that *could change*, should be listed as a dependency. You can see that in the `$(HEADERS)` part of that example.

Comment: Read `x: y z` as "the creation of file x depends on files y and z". Later you may have something like `a: x z` where that means "creating a depends on x and z" which means it also indirectly depends on `y` because `x` does. That's where that flowchart gets really batty, when those dependencies accumulate. It's like saying "sandwich: bread tuna mustard" and then later "lunch: sandwich salad" where your lunch ends up depending indirectly on having bread, tuna and mustard.