# Creating a makefile - (C)

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to create a simple makefile. I have one headerfile: "`guiBuilder.h`". I have another file that will be using it: "`client.c`". The makefile that I am using is:

```
HEADERS = guiBuilder.h

default: program

program.o: client.c $(HEADERS)
    gcc -c client.c -o client.o

program: client.o
    gcc client.o -o Client
```

I found the code for the makefile here:

> [How do I make a simple makefile for gcc on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484817/how-do-i-make-a-simple-makefile-for-gcc-on-linux)

I now get this error when i run it:

> (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:9: recipe for target 'program' failed
>   make: *** [program] Error 1

Comment: Does it build if you don't use a Makefile?

Comment: The rule for `program.o` generates `client.o`

Comment: Also, is there a "main" subroutine in `client.c`? Can you build successfully without using make, and if so, how?

Comment: how many source files do you have ? program.c and client.c ? where is the main program? is there even one?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl **and** the rule for `program` creates `Client`. Yes, this is **not** how make works ...

Comment: The error seems clear to me. Do you have a `main()`? Where is it? Are you compiling the file where it is defined?

Comment: I have no program.c. The way I understood the answer in the link is that all that program stuff stayed where it was, client.c has a main function. Both guiBuilder.c and claint.c comple on their own. Should guiBuilder.c have a main function?

Comment: It seems you misunderstood a very elementary thing about make: The target is the name of the file that is generated by executing the recipe! Change your Makefile accordingly. Rules that don't generate a file named like the target are *phony* rules and should be listed in the prerequisites of the special target `.PHONY` (typically `all`, `clean` etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rules in a make file are of the form:

```
target: dependency1 dependency2 etc
    command to build target
```

`target` is *the name of the file you want to build*. So the line

```
program: client.o
    gcc client.o -o Client
```

Is trying to build a file called `program`. However, the command does not create a file called `program`, it creates a file called `Client`. This is less of a problem than you might think, it just means that the rule is always executed whether `Client` is up to date or not. However, you should change it so the target is the file you are building.

```
Client: client.o
    gcc client.o -o Client
```

By the way, in most *nixes, file names are case sensitive `Client` and `client` are different files on Linux, for example.

That rule has a single dependency: `client.o`. Unfortunately, your make file does not know how to build `client.o` - there is no target called `client.o`.

I am speculating the cause of your error is that you have an old `client.o` hanging about that doesn't have a `main()` function in it. This is why the link (the `gcc` command in the `program` target) is failing.

The target `program.o` has the same problem as the target `program`. You are not building `program.o`, you are building `client.o`. This target needs to be changed to

```
client.o: client.c $(HEADERS)
    gcc -c client.c -o client.o
```

which is happily the dependency for your `Client` target.

**Note** The indentation for the command part of a `make` rule has to be done with a tab. If copy-pasting my answer or any of the other answers, or the answers in the linked question, please make sure your indents are tabs, not spaces.

**Update** (the issue with `test()` being an undefined reference)

If you have a function in `guiBuilder.c` that has a prototype in `guiBuilder.h` you'll need to compile `guiBuilder.c` and add it to the link phase.

Your rule for `guiBuilder.o` will look very similar to the rule for `client.o`

```
guiBuilder.o: guiBuilder.c $(HEADERS)
    gcc -c guiBuilder.c -o guiBuilder.o
```

Then you need to add `guiBuilder.o` as a dependency of `Client`

```
Client: client.o guiBuilder.o
    gcc client.o guiBuilder.o -o Client
```

You may have noticed that you now have two rules for creating `.o` files that are identical other than the names of the source and object files. The accepted answer to [the question that you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484817/how-do-i-make-a-simple-makefile-for-gcc-on-linux) shows how you modify the make file so you only need to define the rule once.

Comment: Ok so now I get client.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `test' when i run the makefile. I have included the guiBuilder.h in client.c

Comment: @ChristopherLittlewood Where is `test` declared?

Comment: Yes. test is declared in guiBuilder.c and is referenced in guiBuilder.h

Comment: I then call it in client.c

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to change the reference from guiBuilder.h to guiBuilder.c in client.c

Comment: @ChristopherLittlewood No, that's wrong. You need to keep guiBuilder.h as is and add guiBuilder.o to the link line. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to read the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf) to get a better understanding of how `make` command and `makefile` works.

To answer your question, in short, Makefile consists of several things out of which the basic things are `target`, `dependency` and `recipe`. In the following manner

```
target: dependency  
        recipe
```

When you run `make` command, it searches for a file with name `Makefile` or `makefile` and it starts parsing target and dependency and executes the recipe for that target.

In your makefile you want to create final binary with name `program` but you don't have `program.c` so your makefile should go something like below:

```
HEADERS = guiBuilder.h

all: program

client.o: client.c $(HEADERS)
          gcc -c client.c

program: client.o
         gcc client.o -o program
```

Comment: Why did you reorder the rules? Their order doesn't matter at all, except that the first rule appearing is automatically the *default* rule.

Comment: Edited the rules to have serial order.