# Error while doing make: mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target

Tags: c, makefile, build, mingw32

I have to create a Makefile which creates a single executable from the .c files in different folders. The .c files include header files from any of these folders. The root directory has 3 sub directories x/y, x/z, a, all these sub directories have some .c and .h files. I want to compile the program from the root directory.
The nature of these sub directories is that new .c files may be added/removed anytime so it is not possible to hard code their names in the Makefile.

So far I have created this Makefile

```
CC = gcc
INCLUDES = -Ix/y -Ix/z -Ia -Ilib/include
LIB = -lp -lq -lr

demo: x/y/*_d.o x/z/*_l.o a/*_m.o
    $(CC) $^ $(LIB) -Llib -o b/demo.exe

%_d.o:: x/y/%.c
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $<

%_l.o:: x/z/%.c
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $<

%_m.o:: a/%.c
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $<
```

I need a solution that will take care of this scenario on its own. Also, if a single file is added to one of these folders then only its dependencies should be built instead of building all .c files all over again.
TIA.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484817/how-do-i-make-a-simple-makefile-for-gcc-on-linux/1484873#1484873

Comment: regarding: `INCLUDES = -Ix/y -Ix/z -Ia -Ilib/include`  Per your question, there is no `lib/include`

Comment: strongly suggest using: `SRC := $(wildcard x/y/*.c) $(wildcard x/z/*.c ) $(wildcard x/a/*.c )`   Then `OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)`  then `INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)`  Then `DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)`   Then use  `gcc` to produce the dependency files.  Then at the end of the makefile use: `ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"` newline
`-include $(DEP)` newline `endif`  then the compile statement would be: `%.o: %.c %.d` newline tab `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@`  Note: `CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`

Comment: by sending some options to the gcc prepossess step, using `-MD`  (or similar) the pre-processer will generate the dependency file before actually compiling the source code

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly there. You just need a simple rule to compile .c into a .o, something like

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $<

Dependencies with wildcards are OK.